# ERROR : Expression must have class type?

Tags: c++, loops

I am writing a program for class that manages a Hotel.  This Report1 function is supposed to list all the occupied rooms and which customer is in each room.  I have the code written, but i am getting a error in the condition statement of my nested FOR loop. The compiler is underlining **iRoom** in the loop............ for(int j = 0; j < **iRoom**.customerIDinRoom.....it is saying the iRoom expression must have a class type, but I gave it a class type when I declared it in the first FOR loop(of type Room).  Any suggestioins?

```
string Hotel::Report1()
{

string result;
for(int i=0;i<listofrooms.size();i++)
{
    Room iRoom = listofrooms.get(i);
    result+= padLeft(intToString(iRoom.roomID),' ',8)+" "+
        padRight(iRoom.name,' ',20) + " "+
        padLeft(intToString(iRoom.floor),' ',8) + " " +
        padLeft(intToString(iRoom.number),' ',8) + " " +
        padLeft(intToString(iRoom.basePriceInSeason),' ',8) + " " +
        padLeft(intToDollarString(iRoom.basePriceOutOfSeason),' ',8) + "\n";

    for(int j = 0; j < iRoom.customerIDinRoom.size(); j++)
    {
        int cusID= iRoom.customerIDinRoom[j];
        Customer & cus = listofcustomers.getByID(cusID);
        result+= padLeft(intToString(cus.customerID),' ',18)+" "+
            padRight(cus.name,' ',20) + " "+
            padRight(cus.phoneNumber,' ',10) + " " +
            padRight(cus.ccNumber,' ',20) + "\n";

    }
}
return result;
}
```

This is the Room class declaration

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Hotel;

class ListOfRooms;

class Room
{
friend class ListOfRooms;
friend class Hotel;
public:
Room(string n,int flo,int num,int bpin, int bpos);
Room();
void addCusID(int cusID){customerIDinRoom = cusID;}
void removeCustomerID(int cusID) { customerIDinRoom = 0;}

private:
string name; //BUILDING
int floor;
int number;
int basePriceInSeason;
int basePriceOutOfSeason;
int roomID;
int customerIDinRoom; //not pushback, will be assignment
};
```

Comment: can you put the class declaration here as well?

Comment: `iRoom.customerIDinRoom[i].size();`? Can't tell without knowing the types, etc.

Comment: @Jesse I just tried that, when I do that, the error move from iRoom to the  [i], saying  expression must have pointer - to - object type

Comment: `customerIDinRoom` is of type `int`. It's a primitive data type, and doesn't have a `size()` member (what language are you coming from?) and you can't use array notation on it. `iRoom.customerIDinRoom` will give you the correct syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is that `customerIDInRoom` is an `int`, but you are calling a `size` method on it. If you are trying to loop from 0 to `customerIDInRoom-1` then you can simply remove the `size()` call. If you need to keep a range of customerIDInRoom ints (as suggested by your "no pushback" comment in the code), then you would most likely need a [standard library container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). Which one to use depends on your requirements. All of these have a `size()` method.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that an `int`, which is how you declared `customerIDinRoom`, does not have a `size()` method, but you're calling it anyway. Declare it as something sane, such as `std::vector<int>` and it should work.

Also:

```
Room iRoom = listofrooms.get(i);
```

This is copying the room from `listofrooms` into `iRoom`. This is more work than necessary; you should use a reference instead:

```
const Room& iRoom(listofrooms.get(i));
```